# What happens if I maintain W/L ratio but change the size of PMOS/NMOS transistors in an op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, cmos

I am designing a two-stage op-amp with 45 nm technology. This is limiting the size of the common-source amplifier PMOS transistor size to 10 μm. I have found designs online, however, when I maintain the W/L ratio but reduce the dimensions of the transistor, I can never reproduce the same Bode plots.

Comment: You're definitely going to lower the parasitic capacitances, which will affect your frequency response. You'll also increase your on resistance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.